# Can I use a researchgate article on my websites resource page?

Tags: research-process, citations, website

I am involved with Vinpro's Gen-Z viticulture project and we are busy establishing a website to document our demo results and findings.
I am just wondering if it is possible to use a researchgate article on our resource page? If so, how do you reference or is there any contact email address where I could direct this question to?

Comment: Define "researchgate article", is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

ResearchGate is usually not the original source of the article. It should be clear from the paper where it was published. Use that as the source.